# Adding basket icon quantity of products in the basket in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am a beginner web developer. I use in my project Bootstrap 4.

I have this code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg text-body px-md-0 pb-md-0 navbar-light w-100">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu"
            aria-controls="navbarmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <form class="mx-lg-5">
                <div class="inner-addon rounded-0 navbar-search-form">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Szukaj produktu"
                           aria-label="Szukaj produktu"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false">Option <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false">Option <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="img/profile.jpg" class="pl-lg-4 pr-2"><span class="d-lg-none d-xl-inline">Zaloguj się</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="img/basket.jpg" class="pl-lg-4 pr-2"><span class="d-lg-none d-xl-inline">Koszyk</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Preview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/

I need to add the number of products in the basket to my basket icon as this screen:
https://ibb.co/PcvM9Dr

How can I make it?

Please help me

Comment: you want this JS or jQuery or you just want to show 5 products in your basket.

Comment: I need only add circle with number :) I need html and css - no js / jQuery :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

Additional CSS :

```
.count{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 60px;
    background: #ff420f;
}
```

Finally in HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item position-relative">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="img/basket.jpg" class="pl-lg-4 pr-2">
    <span class="badge badge-primary count">5</span >
    <span class="ml-2 d-lg-none d-xl-inline">Koszyk</span></a>
</li>
```

Dont forget to add class **.position-relative** inside **li.nav-item**

Comment: Thank you, http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/ - is small problem with formatting.

Comment: "koszyk" skip to next line - not as https://ibb.co/PcvM9Dr